# Minimal Java installation for Linux with no GUI

Tags: java, headless

I'm working on a CentOS 6.3 x86_64 minimal OS (installed using the netinstall ISO).

This system is not expected to run anything beyond console apps/services and Tomcat7. When I attempt to install OpenJDK 1.7, it lists some x11 packages as dependencies. For my purpose, not even awt is needed. And therefore, if possible, I would like to avoid installing all the fonts, x11, etc.

Does there exist a Java/JRE version that comes without the UI pieces?

Comment: I believe Java installs as a whole package, removing classes can get you troubles, besides, it only take you ~250 MB

Comment: I'm afraid there's no such compact version. Some web applications still need fonts to render a bitmap picture and display it to end user. If you don't like those dependencies, maybe you can try the [JDK shipped by Oracle](http://java.sun.com).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't know CentOS, but usually their is an OpenJDK `-headless` package in distributions that doesn't include GUI components, and normally no dependencies to X11 packages.

For instance debian [provide one](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/openjdk-7-jre-headless) package and ArchLinux [too](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/jre7-openjdk-headless/). If your distribution doesn't include it, you can maybe have a look at these to see how it is build.

Comment: Thanks @StreakyCobra. Looks like CentOS does not know of one yet. I'll mark your response as the answer.

Comment: There is a similar [question](http://superuser.com/questions/589777/compiling-openjdk-7-without-x/589984?noredirect=1) on SuperUser where we are looking for a solution (in the comments), but without results for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could remake the package from the source package and split the x11 deps into another package, it's just not a "A+" package, more like a "B-". I assume this is only because you don't wish to install all the x11 libs it depends on?

Alternatively, you could simply use the provided tarball instead of the rpm.